# Polynomial $x^3-2x^2-3x-4=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be three distinct roots of the polynomial $x^3-2x^2-3x-4=0$. Then find $$\frac{\alpha^6-\beta^6}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{\beta^6-\gamma^6}{\beta-\gamma}+\frac{\gamma^6-\alpha^6}{\gamma-\alpha}.$$
I tried to solve with Vieta's theorem. We have 
$$\begin{align}
\alpha+\beta+\gamma &= 2, \\ 
\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha &= -3, \\ 
\alpha\beta\gamma &= 4.
\end{align}$$
For example, $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)=10$ and similarly, we can find $\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3$...

But it has very long and messy solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By long division, the remainder of $x^6$, when divided by $x^3-2x^2-3x-4$,
is $77x^2+100x+96$. So we know that
$$
\alpha^6=77\alpha^2+100\alpha+96
$$
and the same with other roots. Therefore you are looking at the sum
$$
\begin{aligned}
S&=\frac{77(\alpha^2-\beta^2)+100(\alpha-\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}+\text{cyclic}\\
&=77(\alpha+\beta)+100+\text{cyclic}\\
&=154(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+300\\
&=608
\end{aligned}
$$
by the (Vieta) relations you have.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ satisfy $x^6=ax^2+bx+c$, then the first term is $a(\alpha+\beta)+b$, and we have similar expressions for the others, so the desired sum is $2a(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+3b=4a+3b$.
To find $a$ and $b$, square $x^3$ and reduce modulo the given polynomial.

Comment: Wow. That's nice idea! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=3u$, $\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=3v^2$ and $\alpha\beta\gamma=w^3$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\alpha^6-\beta^6}{\alpha-\beta}=\sum_{cyc}(2\alpha^5+\alpha^4\beta+\alpha^4\gamma+\alpha^3\beta^2+\alpha^3\gamma^2)=$$
$$=2(243u^5-405u^3v^2+135uv^4+45u^2w^3-15v^2w^3)+$$
$$+81u^3v^2-81uv^4-9u^2w^3+15v^2w^3+$$
$$+27uv^4-18u^2w^3-3v^2w^3=$$
$$=9(54u^5-81u^3v^2+7u^2w^3+24uv^4-2v^2w^3).$$
Now, use your work.

I got $608$.

Comment: Your solution is nice! But how did you get $2(243u^5-405u^3v^2+135uv^4+45u^2w^3-15v^2w^3)+81u^3v^2-81uv^4-9u^2w^3+15v^2w^3+27uv^4-18u^2w^3-3v^2w^3$

Comment: @Mutse I work with symmetric polynomials and I just know these expressions. But you can get it by the following way: $\alpha^5+\beta^5+\gamma^5=\sum\limits_{cyc}\alpha^3\sum\limits_{cyc}\alpha^2-\sum\limits_{sym}\alpha^3\beta^2=(27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3)(9u^2-6v^2)-(27uv^4-18u^2w^3-3v^2w^3)=...$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ok, I got it. Thank you for nice solution!

Comment: @Mutse You are welcome!

Comment: @Mutse I fixed my mistake. Indeed, it's should be equal to $608$.

Comment: Also, I'm a bit curious about the reason for you including the factor $3$ into the elementary symmetric polynomials. I sort of see the point in that you then write everything in terms of averages. Is that a trade secret or simply something that comes up frequently when dealing three variable inequalities.

Answer (score -1):

The final answer I got is 608.
The answer for this question is provided  in the given pdf 
By Vieta's theorem and using some special algebraic identities that are prevelant in India..
[Click on the link .THE whole values are achieved by some easy calculations](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XGpAYzUz0ddklwow0OBK31NKFN1rOFQW)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.